# Remove a tag using emmet plugin for vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have been using emmet for vim for some time now. Quite useful.

I have used .class1>b>em to expand quite often.

I have the following code:

```
<li><b>Point 1</b></li>
```

I just want to remove `<li>` and `</li>`. I tried Control Y - k by placing the cursor at all points in the line in normal mode. I am able to either delete the line or delete everything except `<li></li>`.

How do I get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Lets define a new shortcut for it (`\q` -- please choose a better one)

```
:map \q "aditcat<C-x><C-r>a<ESC>
```

Explanation (first position in the tag to be removed):

- `"adit`  delete inside the current tag and save it in register `a`
- `cat`    change arround the current tag (including the tag) by
- `<C-x><C-r>a<ESC>` the contents of register `a`

After testing, insert it in your .vimrc or similar.

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to delete surrounding tag.

```
dst
```

In your code: `<li><b>Point 1</b></li>` type `dst` when your cursor is over `li` tag will give you desired result. It is very handy, because you can also remove `b` tag when your cursor is on the text as this deletes the closest surrounding tag.